# Discord.py: Counting the number of reactions by unique users

Tags: python, discord.py

I have to gather the count of unique users who reacted to a message in discord.

I can't use the `reaction.count` property, as it only lists the total number of users who reacted with that specific emoji, rather than the total number of users who reacted to the message. This means that we can have duplicates in a case like this:

```
This is a message that someone reacted to!
(A)31, (B)12, (C)55
```

In the above case, if a user reacted both B and C, they'll be counted twice if I simply sum the total reactions.

Even worse is a case like this:

```
A different discord message!
(N)1, (I)1, (C)1, (E)1
```

Same problem, but in this case a single user reacted four times to spell something.

What I have right now to avoid duplicates works, as follows:

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.utils import get

...
@tree.command(guild=discord.Object(id=GUILD_ID))
async def get_unique_reactions(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    gallery = interaction.guild.get_channel(int(DISCORD_GALLERY_ID))
    async for message in gallery.history(after=week_ago, limit=None):
        reaction_ids = set()
        for reaction in message.reactions:
            async for user in reaction.users():
                reaction_ids.add(user.id)
        print(f"{reaction_ids}")

...
```

(the above code is slightly paraphrased)

Unfortunately, if there's a large number of messages and reactions to count, this code will quickly hit the rate limit, due to each user queried by `reaction.users` being an API call.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to get the users from a list of reactions is the one you're currently using.

Except keeping track locally of all the reactions when they're added I don't think that you have another option.

If you don't care about the function taking a bit of time to execute you could handle the rate limit and keep the system you've made.

Comment: Sounds about right - I have some situation-dependent optimizations that I've added to the code that could help other people, so I'll post those here in a moment, but otherwise I agree that I'll probably just have to stick to this general method unless someone is magic

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, I'll update this with the API optimizations that were helpful for my specific situation.

In my case, the full function (which you can find [here](https://github.com/Scew5145/IF-Discord-Utils/blob/main/FeedbackBot/main.py)) was meant to get a list of the top 15 messages by unique reactions, so I can skip using `reaction.users()` on messages where the sum of all reactions' counts on the current message is less than the 15th most reacted to message, like this:

```
async def get_top_sprites(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    gallery = interaction.guild.get_channel(int(DISCORD_GALLERY_ID))
    now = dt.now()
    week_ago = now - timedelta(days=7)
    top_sprites = list()
    tiebreak_counter = 0
    message_counter = 0
    await interaction.response.send_message("This operation will take a while! Check back in this channel in half an hour.", ephemeral=False)
    async for message in gallery.history(after=week_ago, limit=None):
        message_counter += 1
        if message_counter % 500 == 0:
            await interaction.channel.send(f"Parsed {message_counter} gallery posts")
        reaction_ids = set()
        # api usage optimization: if the sum of all reaction.count is < the X most reacted to sprite,
        # we know that we can skip this message for the top X number sprites
        # this is because each reaction can only be reacted to once, 
        # so sums of reactions.count will always be >= total unique reactions
        reaction_sum = sum(reaction.count for reaction in message.reactions)
        if len(top_sprites) == top_count and reaction_sum < top_sprites[0][0]:
            continue
        for reaction in message.reactions:
            async for user in reaction.users():
                reaction_ids.add(user.id)

        heapq.heappush(top_sprites, (len(reaction_ids), tiebreak_counter, message))
        if len(top_sprites) > top_count:
            heapq.heappop(top_sprites)
        tiebreak_counter += 1
```